# A keybindings.json per workspace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to have a keybindings.json as part of the workspace settings instead of the user settings?

Since I have specific tasks associated to my workspace, I would also like to be able to assign workspace-specific shortcuts. Because I would use these shortcuts on my separate Windows and Linux environments, I would not prefer to see these key binding definitions end up amongst my environment-specific user settings.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not possible. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4504) Alexandru Dima (alexandrudima) explains why they do not want to add this feature and furthermore suggests to create your custom extension that contributes only keybindings to share them.

Comment: there is another issue raising this question in the backlog: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23757

Comment: I think the explanation on the GitHub issues is irrelevant to the question. He explains why he thinks it does not make sense to _share_ key bindings. All good. But the question is not about sharing, the question is about ability to have same shortcut doing different things depending on the workspace. In the same vein "create your custom extension that contributes only keybindings to share" is this answer does nothing to address the original question since it did not ask about sharing

Answer (score 37):

Not a perfect solution, but I found a workaround to create a keybinding that can be activated at a workspace level.

In the workspace `.vscode/settings.json` file, set a new setting to true.  (Because the setting is not registered by vscode or any extension, it will be displayed faded out in the editor - This is OK):

```
  "workspaceKeybindings.myAwesomeTask.enabled": true // setting can be anything you want
```

Then create the keyboard shortcut in the user `keybindings.json`, and add a "when" condition for the setting you created:

```
{ 
  "key": "ctrl+; ctrl+n",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "My Awesome Task",
  "when": "config.workspaceKeybindings.myAwesomeTask.enabled" // Must be "config.{settingName}"
},
```

This keybinding can be set as active in any workspaces you want.

Comment: This saved my entire day!
Works flawless.

Comment: Excellent! I'm lovin' it!

Comment: is it possible to send different `args` for different workspace? For example I would like to run `npm start` in one workspace and `npm run dev` in another, using the same shortcut

Comment: @Gangula An easy way to accomplish what you are trying to do would be to setup separate entries in `keybindings.json` as described above, one for `npm start` and one for `npm run dev` with each using different settingName in the when clause.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisBain. I had actually taken inspiration from your approach & [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189220/6908282) to come up with a different one which works very well for me. I added it in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76497629/6908282).

Comment: @Gangula I'm glad you found a solution for your use case

Comment: There is perfect to me! 

Negtive config is like this:
{"when": "!config.workspaceKeybindings.myAwesomeTask.enabled && (HERE IS OTHER CONDITIONS)"}

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Is there a convention for these arbitrary settings, hopefully not to be faded by vscode?

Comment: @momvart Nope, no convention.  In my example, I used a name that would hopefully make sense when I see it 2 years later and can't remember what it is LOL.  But whatever setting name you use, it will be an unknown setting to VS Code (because no extension defines it) and will be faded out in the JSON editor.  I'm not aware of any way around that with this solution.

Answer (score 16):

as of July 10, 2022, it doesn't seem possible to have a `.vscode/keybindings.json` per workspace, however it is possible to get keybindings that are active only when you're in a certain folder:

In your keybindings file, you can put:

```json
[
  { 
    "key": "...",
    "command": "..." ,
    "when": "resourceDirname == '/Users/johndoe/path/to/folder'",
    ...
  },
]
```

---

You also have all these other contexts:

```
resource: "vscode-userdata:/Users/johndoe/path/to/file.json"
resourceDirname: "/Users/johndoe/path/to/"
resourceExtname: ".json"
resourceFilename: "file.json"
resourceLangId: "jsonc"
resourcePath: "/Users/johndoe/path/to/file.json"
resourceScheme: "vscode-userdata"
```

and more...

---

To find all possible context keys:

1. Run the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` vscode command
2. Then run the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` vscode command and then click anywhere
3. Expand the context object in the console, and you should see a full list of context key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this by making using of `tasks.json` and a custom global keyboard shortcut. I have also written [an article](https://anweshgangula.hashnode.dev/use-same-shortcut-for-different-scripts-in-vs-code) detailing out the entire process to set it up.

Below is the summary:

1. create a task in your workspace `.vscode/tasks.json` called `startDev` - for example to run `npm run dev` command, like below:

   ```json
      {
        "label": "startDev",
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "start:host" // you can even use shell scripts
      }
   ```
2. add a custom shortcut in your global `keybindings.json` file like below:

   ```json
   {
       "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
       "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
       "args": "startDev",
   },
   ```
3. Now, you can add a task in all your projects' `.vscode/tasks.json` with same label and replace it with your desired task.

---

- This approach is re-usable and extensible. You will need to set this up once and you'll be able to use it in any number of projects/workspaces
- Another benefit of using `tasks.json` is, it has flags to switch commands based on the OS and also can use various terminals.

[This article](https://anweshgangula.hashnode.dev/use-same-shortcut-for-different-scripts-in-vs-code) details the process and benefits of this approach in detail.

Comment: This is a clever solution for using the same keyboard shortcut to run different VS Code tasks is different workspaces.

Note that the first step (creating a task in the User `tasks.json` is not required.  This task works as a default for the keybinding (if a task with that same label is not defined in the workspace), but the the solution would still work without it.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your comment. if the `tasks.json` is not defined, then the keybinding would not be able to run any task right?

Comment: In addition to defining tasks for a workspace in `.vscode/tasks.json`, you can also define [User Level Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_user-level-tasks) via `tasks.json` in the VS Code User directory.  Step 1 doesn't clearly state the task being created is a workspace-level task, and I mistakenly read it as a user-level task.  Now that I understand that step 1 is to create a workspace-level task, you are correct and can ignore my earlier comment  :-)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of User Level Tasks. Thanks for the reference and the clarification