# Run custom commands as run configurations in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom run configuration in Visual Studio Code, and am not succeeding in finding any documentation describing my use case.

I want to make a Run Configuration that runs arbitrary commands that I can set to run my code. This is neccecary because the language I am using doesn't have extensions providing run configurations.

I did find that this is possible with tasks, but I cannot figure out how to run a task by pressing F5 (like you would with a run configuration).

So, this is what I am looking to do: Define *something* that will run a command (run.exe ${currently selected VSCode file}) when I press F5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define this task and put it in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
  "label": "Run current",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "run.exe ${file}"
}
```

Then add an F5 keybinding in `keybindings.json`

```
{ "key": "F5", "command": "-workbench.action.debug.start" },
{ "key": "F5", "command": "-workbench.action.debug.continue" },
{
  "key": "F5",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "Run current"
}
```

Comment: where does the first go?

Comment: @Tuor place it in your `.vscode/tasks.json`

Comment: To avoid being prompted for result scanning, I included ```"problemMatcher": []``` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/58782412/11262633.

Comment: @rioV8 overriding global shortcuts for project level tasks?!

Comment: @AntonDuzenko if the OP want to use `F5`, be my guest, he can also choose a different shortcut like `F20` (if he has that key), the global shortcuts are suggestions you can completely redefine all of them.

Comment: Note that you can restrict keybindings to only be active in specific folders, as described over on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927298/740553 (which is not great, but better than a global override)