# VSCode debugging specific configuration with CodeLLVM

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I was able to generate a `launch.json` file with the VSCode Rust debugger; The tool is smart enough to create a configuration array with multiple configurations, one for each package in my project; so far so good. Except that a `Start Debugging` always choose the first configuration in the list.

Do I need to place the configuration I want to launch at the beginning of the array, or is there a way to specify a specific name in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Run and Debug sidebar ([image: Debug sidebar icon], Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+D), and in the list choose the configuration to launch.

[image: Choose a debug configuration]

For one time, you can open the Command Palette (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P), and choose "Debug: Select and Start Debugging". Then choose the desired configuration.

If you want to bind it to a shortcut, edit your keybindings.json and add:

```json
{
    "key": /* shortcut, e.g. */ "ctrl+alt+k ctrl+alt+k",
    "command": "debug.startFromConfig",
    "args": /* full launch configuration. you cannot rely on configurations specified in launch.json, unfortunately */ {}
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to apply keybindings per-workspace. See [A keybindings.json per workspace in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945319/a-keybindings-json-per-workspace-in-visual-studio-code).

See [Allow key binding for individual launch configurations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97921) for more.

Comment: This. And as far as I know, there's no command to `Run ...<ask me>`. F5 (default key?) will launch the selected one but you have to make your way there to select it. I never looked into ways to set a keyboard shortcut to launch different ones, perhaps that's possible.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini There is the command "Select and Start Debugging" and you can bind it to a keybinding, but I don't know a way to associate a keybdinding with a specific launch configuration, unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh good point. I'm not too familiar with vscode so I don't know either. I run VSCodium instead and it (naturally) is the same.

Comment: Found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97921.

Comment: From the github link: "Just in case, in a few simple steps you can get started writing your own extension". Have they ever heard of NIH and DRY? Sure,, I can rewrite vscode to support configuration launch too!